# Create Win7 batch file to copy files out from all folders

Tags: batch-file, copy, move, xcopy

I am trying to write a batch file to do the following tasks:

1. I have 20 sub-folders(milk, cheese, protein...) within one **folder(ABC)**. Each subfolder has about 15 monthly files in .csv, named as 2013-10-01, 2013-09-02, 2013-07-31.....
2. These monthly files are added on a monthly basis and there is no pattern regarding their names, e.g., it could be the first day for October but the fourth day for November. So each month I add a new file to each subfolder, i.e., the number of files is increasing;
3. Every month, for each subfolder/category, I want to copy the most recent 9 monthly files to another location, say, **folder CDE**;
4. After copying them to **folder CDE**, I put them all together to one file with a unique name defined using the current time(%%d-%%e-%%f). In such way I can have the monthly file for each category every month.

I am able to write the code for step 4 and am wondering if any of you could help on **step 3**. I now have to manually copy and paste the 9 files from all 20 subfolders every time. It is very inefficient and I know some batch commands could definitely make the process quicker and easier.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT** fixed the 'copy all files' issue.

This should do the following: (change c:\cde and c:\abc)

1) copy 9 most recent files from the folder
2) merge them all into one file called foldername-HHMMSS (from the time variable)
3) The foldername-HHMMSS file is created in the c:\ABC folder
4) remove the 9 copied files
5) repeat for each folder

```
@echo off
set "source=D:\ABC"
set "target=C:\files\CDE"
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
md "%target%" 2>nul
for /d /r "%source%" %%a in (*) do (
  pushd "%%a"
     set num=0
         for /f "delims=" %%b in ('dir /o-d /b /a-d') do (
           set /a num+=1
           if !num! LSS 10 copy "%%b" "%target%" >nul
         )
     set t=!time!
     set t=!t:~0,2!!t:~3,2!!t:~6,2!
     copy "%target%\*.*" "%source%\%%~nxa-!t!" >nul
     echo "%source%\%%~nxa-!t!" created from "%%a"
     if defined target del "%target%\*.*?"
  popd
)
pause
```

Comment: Hi foxdrive, thanks for the swift reply. Your code is a bit high-level to me and it didn't work for copy-paste (yes I changed the source and target). I am still digesting it and will let you know when I understand it.

Comment: Copy it again.  I had made an error and missed the tildas in one command.  I tested it and it works here.

Comment: The new code works perfect other than it copies all file from each subfolder but not the most recent 9. I changed the number 10 to 9 and even 5 but it still copies all files.

Comment: My apologies.  When I tested it I didn't check the file content so that bug slipped by me - It was using the wrong variable.   Try the edited code above.  I simplified it a little too.

Comment: I should also mention that `!` characters in the path or filename could be an issue.

Comment: Your code works like a charm now! Thank you very much! What do you mean by "! could be an issue"?

Comment: With delayed expansion `!` becomes a poison character in strings.  If your folder names or filenames contains an `!` then that file will probably fail to be processed correctly.

Answer (score 0):

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir abc /b /o-d') do (set /a a=0&for /f "delims=" %%j in ('dir "abc\%%~i" /b /o-d') do (set /a a+=1&if !a! LEQ 9 (copy /Y "abc\%%~i\%%~j" cde)))
```

put this in the same folder that abc and cde are in
if this isn't what you wanted, would you please elaborate.

Comment: Hi nephi12, thanks for replying. Your code successfully copies the most recent 9 files from each subfolder under ABC. However, every time it copies files from a subfolder, the new files replaces existing files. So by the end of the day, I can only get the 9 files from the first subfolder. I guess we may need to merge the 9 files to one before copying from the next subfolder. Thanks!

Comment: Hi nephi12, in fact I was trying to merge them myself by writing another merging batch file (merge.bat) and calling it from your code(copy.bat). I didn't get any success though; I guess I called merge.bat in a wrong place in your code? The merge.bat works fine on its own.